# Encrypt file as string through HTTP with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, encryption

I'm looking for advice about what I want to do.
Currently, I use a server A to request files from a server B, by HTTP.

The server B check if the requested path exists and return the file content, as string, through HTTP. Everything is in clear.

What I want to do is to crypt the transfer, so just before send back the file content to the server A, I want to protect it in a way the server B will be able to reverse.

I want it fast, secure (salt) and not too big. (The files can contain thousands of characters)

What's the best way to achieve that? I use node.js with both servers.

I'm also thinking about adding an authentication and do it through HTTPS to secure the content, assuming the protection (cryptage/etc...) cannot be broken, is it useful? (Auth can limit the requests and avoid to use too much bandwidth, but does HTTPS will really be worth it?)

I don't know too much about cryptage, it's maybe not the right word to use there, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encrypt the contents of an HTTP request, use HTTPS. Don't bother reinventing the wheel.

HTTPS will make it so that someone able to intercept the communication between these servers will not be able to read the files you're sending back and forth. http://book.mixu.net/node/ch10.html describes the steps to turn on HTTPS in your node application on both the Client and Server. If you are using Nginx or Apache as a proxy in front of your node applications, you can find instructions for them as well.

HTTPS will **NOT** restrict access to the server. For that, you'll need to use an authentication/authorization system for that. http://passportjs.org is a pretty standard NodeJS module for this purpose.

> I want it fast, secure **(salt)** and not too big. (The files can contain thousands of characters)

Salt is a concept that doesn't apply here.

You use a salt on a one-way hash function (like MD5 or SHA) so that if you encrypt the same string different times, it doesn't get the same result.

If User A and B both have a password of "Password123", they will be 2 different hashed strings in the database. This means that cracking the password of User A will not automatically crack User B's password.

Comment: For passwords you should really be using something like bcrypt or pbkdf2 instead.

Comment: Yeah, that is the way to go. I was trying to explain the concept of a salt and jumped on the first things that came to mind. You should never use SHA1 or MD5 to actually secure a password.

Comment: HTTPS is secure, theorically, I'm wondering what the NSA think about that. ^^
Okay, so I'll wait to use HTTPS, it's complicated, I never succeed before and I have to configure 5 different apps with HTTPS if I do it. Authentication seems required here.
Thnks for the information about the salt, I used bcrypt but I don't anymore, way too big and it's really shitty to make it work with windows... I use something else much more simple. The native nodejs library. Thanks!